# Can't use Raster with vector layer

Tags: raster, openlayers

I'm trying to clip a raster layer with a vector layer, but openlayers seems to fail when it tries to call getImage on the vector layer?

What am I doing wrong?

```js
proj4.defs('EPSG:3006', '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
var geoJSONGeometry = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [458243.52, 6249847.520000001],
            [457869.44, 6249619.040000001],
            [458086.72000000003, 6249146.400000001],
            [458601.92, 6249137.440000001],
            [458942.4, 6249697.440000001],
            [458243.52, 6249847.520000001]
        ]
    ]
};

var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var olGeometry = format.readGeometryFromObject(geoJSONGeometry);
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    renderMode: 'image',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [
            new ol.Feature(olGeometry)
        ]
    }),
    style: () => new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ff0000'
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 10,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ff0000'
            })
        })
    })
});

var raster = new ol.source.Raster({
    sources: [osmLayer, vectorLayer],
    threads: 0, //todo: remove this limitation!
    operation: (pixels) => {
        if (pixels[1][3] == 0) {
            return [0, 0, 0, 1];
        } else {
            return pixels[0];
        }
    }
});

const resultLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: raster
});


var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        resultLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [457847, 6249963],
      zoom: 14,
      projection: 'EPSG:3006',
    })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4p209wt/)

Edit: i get the following error `imageSource.getImage is not a function` and `imageSource` is the VectorLayer.

Comment: There was a bug in OpenLayers 5.  I suggest you use version 6 with a VectorImage layer https://jsfiddle.net/hdot0m86/  Also (in any version) the OSM should be a source, not a layer

Comment: @Mike i would love to upgrade to OL 6, but the TypeScript definitions seem to lag behind alot, the official is still at 5.3.X and the unofficial is at 6.0.1 but still has a todo note..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by creating the raster layer after the map had been initialized, no idea why this is required but it seems to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/pxc80g25/